# Javascript display and CSS

Tags: javascript, css

I had to create a "fake" weather page using Javascript only. I am struggling with the layout and have a couple of questions:

- I tried everything to include padding above my "h1" title but nothing works.
- I want the weather photos and infos to display in the middle of the box (as it does in day0) but I cannot get it to do it.
- Would you recommend to break my .js file into different ones for each function or is it ok to put it all in one. I want to avoid it being confusing ?

HTML:

```
<!doctype html>

<html lang="en">

<head> 
 <meta charset="utf-8"> 
 <title>AccuMeteo</title>
 <meta name="description" content="AccuMeteo Weather Forecast">
 <meta name="keywords" content="Daily and Weekly Weather forecast">
 <link href="css/accumeteo.css" rel="stylesheet">
   <script type="text/javascript" src="js/accumeteo.js"></script>   
</head>

<body>
   <!-- wrapper  section starts -->
    <div id="wrapper">


        <!-- header  section starts -->
    <div id="header">

    <img src="images/header.jpg" width="975" height="220" alt="Blue Sky Header" class="floatleft">

    </div>

        <!-- header  section ends -->

  <!-- menu  section starts -->     
    <div id="menu">
        <ul>
                <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="vancouver.html" id="current" class="first">Vancouver</a></li>
                <li><a href="dallas.html">Dallas</a></li>
                <li><a href="ny.html">New York</a></li>
                    <li><a href="placeholder.html">Contact Us</a></li>
            </ul>
    </div>

        <!-- menu  section ends -->

<div id="content">

<div id="city">
    <h1>Vancouver, BC</h1>
</div>    

<div id="date">
    <noscript> <div>! JavaScript is not enabled.</div> </noscript>

    <div id="PST"></div>
    <div id="year"></div>
    <div id="ordinal"></div>
    <div id="day"></div>
</div>

<div id="panel">


    <div id="day0">
    </div>

    <div id="day1">
    </div>

    <div id="day2">
    </div>

    <div id="day3">
    </div>

    <div id="day4">
    </div>

    <div id="day5">
    </div>

    <div id="day6">
    </div>
</div>

</div>





        <!-- footer section starts -->
    <div id="footer">
        <p class="bottom">Copyright &copy; 2012 JC Design  |  All Rights Reserved  |  <a href="#">Terms and Conditions</a></p>
    </div>
    <!-- foot section ends -->      


    <!-- wrapper section starts -->
  <script>
    displayTime("PST");
</script>
   </div>

</body>
</html>
```

.css

```
/*Homepage* /

/*Body*/
html {background-color: #e2e2e2}

body {
   color: #000; background: #fff;
   font-family: Verdana,helvetica,arial, sans-serif; 
   font-size: 90%;
   text-align: left;
   width: 975px;
   margin-left: auto;
   margin-right: auto;
}

p {
   margin-left: 35px;
   margin-right: 25px;
   text-align: left;
}

/*---------------Navigation  styles-------------------*/

#menu {
  float: left; 
  margin:0;
  padding-top: 0px;
  width: 100%;
  background: #4186d3; color: #04356c;
}  


#menu ul {
  margin: 0px;
  position: relative 
}


#menu ul li {
  display: inline; 
}


#menu ul li a {
  float: left;
  padding: 5px 16px;
  margin-right: 0px;
  background: #4186d3; color: #04356c;
  text-decoration: none;
  border-right: 1px solid #e2e2e2;
}


#menu ul li a:hover {
  color: #04356c; background: #fff;
  text-decoration: underline;
}

#menu li a#current {
  background: #0d56a6; color: #fff;
}

/*Bottom link formatting*/

p.bottom a:link { 
   background: #04356c; color: #fff;
}


p.bottom a:visited { 
   color: #ba1212;
}

p.bottom a:hover {
   color: #f9b41f;  
   text-decoration: none; 
}

p.bottom a:active{
    background: #3ca0d0; color: #000;
}


/*Page wrapper*/
#wrapper {
   margin: 0 auto; 
   width: 975px; 
   text-align: left;
}

/*Banner styles*/

#header {
   background-color: #2d1d06; color: #7d890d;
   font-family: verdana, helvetica, arial, sans-serif;
   font-size: 150%;
   width: 925px;
   padding: 0px;
}


#footer {
   clear: both;
  background: #04356c; color: #fff;
   font-family: Verdana,helvetica, arial, sans-serif;
   font-size: 90%;
   font-weight: normal;
   width: 975px;
   padding-bottom: 3px;
   padding-top: 3px;
}

#footer p {
   text-align: center;
}


.content {
  padding: 0px 0px 0px 160px;
  position: relative;
}


/* Images*/
img { 
   border: 0px; 
   padding: 0px;
}

.floatleft { 
   float: left;
   margin: 0px;
   padding: 0px; 
   border: none;  
}



/*Headings*/
hr{
  position: absolute;
   width: 45%;
   margin-left: 35px;
   margin-right: 45px;
   border: 1px dotted #000; 
}
h1{
   color: #7d890d;
   font-size: 140%;
   font-weight: normal;
   margin-left: 35px;
}

h2{
   color: #052a6e;
   font-weight: normal;
   font-size: 125%;
   margin-left: 35px;
}


/*********************/
/*  Date Properties  */
/*********************/

#date {
   float: right;
   margin: 10px;
}

#day, #ordinal, #year {
   float: right;
}

#ordinal {
   vertical-align: baseline;
   font-size: 0.8em;
   position: relative;
   top: -0.2em;
}


/*  JavaScript Panel Properties  */


#panel {
   font-size: 0.8em;
   width: 100%;
   float: left;
   margin: 5px;
}


#day0, #day1, #day2, #day3, #day4 {
   float: left;
   width: 181px;
   height: 355px;
   border: 1px solid black;
   margin: 4px;
   text-align: center;
}


td,th {
   width: 175px;
   height: 35px;
   font-size: 1.3em;
}

th {
   font-size: 1.5em;
}

#spacerCell {
   height: 70px;
}

.tempLow, .tempHigh {
   font-size: 2em;
   color: blue;
}

.tempHigh {
   color: red;
}
```

.js

```
var thisDate = new Date();
var day = thisDate.getDate();
var dayNames = [ "Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday" ];
var monthNames = [ "January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December" ];

var sun = new Forecast( "sunny.png", "Sunny", 17, 31 );
var clouds = new Forecast( "cloudy.png", "Cloudy", 10, 23 );
var showers = new Forecast( "mix.png", "Mix of Sun and Cloud", 12, 20 );    
var rain = new Forecast( "rain.png", "Rain", 6, 14 );  

var fList = [ sun, clouds, showers, rain ];    
var pList = [ "day0", "day1", "day2", "day3", "day4" ];    

var low, high;


// Functions

function init()
{
    displayDate();
    displayForecast();
}
window.onload=init;


function Forecast( image, title, minTemp, maxTemp )
{
    this.image=image;
    this.title=title;
    this.minTemp=minTemp;
    this.maxTemp=maxTemp;
}


function randomNumber( min, max )
{
    var rand = Math.random() * (max - min + 1) + min;
    rand = Math.floor(rand)
    return rand;
}


function displayTime( timeZone )
{
    var timeE = document.getElementById( timeZone );
    var offset, hh, mm, AMorPM;

    switch ( timeZone )
    {
        case "PST":
            offset = -7;
            break;
        case "EST":
            offset = -4;
            break;
        case "CDT":
            offset = -5;
            break;
        default:
            timeE.innerHTML += "Error!";
    }

    thisDate = calcTime( offset );
    hh = thisDate.getHours();
    mm = thisDate.getMinutes();

    if( mm < 10 ){ mm = "0" + mm; }

    if( hh > 12 )
    {
        hh -= 12;
        AMorPM = " PM";
    }
    else
    {
        AMorPM = " AM";
    }

    timeE.innerHTML += hh + ":" + mm + " " + AMorPM + " (" + timeZone + ")";
}

// This will return a Date object with the city's current time based on that city's "offset" from the GMT.
function calcTime( offset )
{
    var date = new Date();
    date.setTime(date.getTime() + date.getTimezoneOffset()*60*1000 + offset*60*60*1000);
    return date;
}


//This will return a new Date object for a single forecast
function addDays(myDate,days)
{
    return new Date(myDate.getTime() + days*24*60*60*1000);
}


function displayDate()
{
    var dayE = document.getElementById("day");
    var ordinalE = document.getElementById("ordinal");
    var yearE = document.getElementById("year");

    // Display the day of the week and the date (month, day)
    dayE.innerHTML = dayNames[ thisDate.getDay() ] +", ";
    dayE.innerHTML += monthNames[ thisDate.getMonth() ] +" ";
    dayE.innerHTML += " " +day;

    // Function determining which ending to use for the date and displaying it
    switch (day)
    {
        case 1:
        case 21:
        case 31:
            ordinalE.innerHTML += "st";
            break;
        case 2:
        case 22:
            ordinalE.innerHTML += "nd";
            break;
        case 3:
        case 23:
            ordinalE.innerHTML += "rd";
            break;
        default:
            ordinalE.innerHTML += "th";
    }

    // Display the year
    yearE.innerHTML = ", " +thisDate.getFullYear();
}


function getDayTitle( i )
{
    var dayTitle;
    var dayOfWeek = addDays( thisDate, i )
    var d = dayOfWeek.getDay();

    if( d > 6 )
    {
        d -= 7;
    }

    // Function determining which title to use (today, tomorrow, day of the week)
    switch ( i )
    {
        case 0:
            dayTitle = "Today";
            break;
        case 1:
            dayTitle = "Tomorrow";
            break;
        default:
            dayTitle = dayNames[d];
    }
    return dayTitle;
}


function displayForecast()
{
    for( i=0; i < pList.length; i++)
    {
        displayDailyForecast( i );
    }
}


function displayDailyForecast( i )
{
    var forecastE = document.getElementById( pList[i] );
    var forecast = fList[ randomNumber(0,3) ];
    var html = "<table>";

    if( i == 0)
    {
        html += "<tr><td id='spacerCell'></td></tr>"
    }

    html += "<tr><th colspan='2'>" + getDayTitle(i) + "</th></tr>";

    html += "<tr><td colspan='2'><img src='images/" + forecast.image + "' width='100' height='100'></td></tr>";

    html += "<tr><td colspan='2'>" + forecast.title + "</td></tr>";

    getTemp( forecast.minTemp, forecast.maxTemp );
    html += "<tr><td class='tempLow'>"+ low +"&degC</td>";
    html += "<td class='tempHigh'>"+ high +"&degC</td></tr>";

    forecastE.innerHTML += html;
}


function getTemp( min, max )
{
    var t1, t2;

    t1 = randomNumber( min, max );
    t2 = randomNumber( min, max );

    if( t1 < t2 )
    {
        low = t1;
        high = t2;
    }
    else if( t1 > t2 )
    {
        low = t2;
        high = t1;
    }
    else // if t1==t2
    {
        low = t1;
        high = t1 + 1;
    }
}
```

Comment: Any chance you could knock-ip a http://www.JSFiddle.com/ for this?

Comment: Have you tried adding a padding property to the css for h1 tags?

Comment: not .com, http://jsfiddle.net, don't support domain spammers

Comment: "include padding above my `h1`" You probably can't see the margin because it collapses with the one from the element above. To prevent [collapsing margins](http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/collapsingmargins) you need to add a border or tiny padding either to the `h1` or the parent element.

Answer (score 0):

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/PYBS5/2/) you go. Use the padding property for padding, you were using a spacercell td for displaying things in the middle, and no a single js file is fine.

EDIT: Fixed a couple things. You were using a .content selector instead of a #content selector in your css. [Here](http://jsfiddle.net/WMBwM/) is the updated version.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly I want to ask you that do you really need to use table tags for days? I mean cant you use div tags? because in table tag all the inner tags always have relative position.

You can insert div tags inside day0 / day1 etc tags with absolute position and then use
   divId.innerHTML = getDayTitle(i) 
( all your respective methods ) to set the text instead of generating entire table through js.

Secondly if in future if you change the font etc of your text then also table can create problems because it always uses " fit to contents " type method hence tr size may increase depending on your text size

Use div tags and it will surely work :)

Answer (score -2):

For new browsers use flexbox.
http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/flexbox/quick/